# Calling a function/script from other instance of itself

Tags: batch-file

for example this script:

t.cmd

```
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion
cd /D "%~dp0"


set pafIf=%~dp0
call :fIsc "!pafIf:~0,-1!"
goto fIn
:fIsc
set "pafIfZs=%1"
set pafIfZs=!pafIfZs:"=!
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%q in ('dir "!pafIfZs!" /b') do (
    echo "!pafIfZs!\%%q\"
    if exist "!pafIfZs!\%%q\" (
        call :fIsc "!pafIfZs!\%%q"
    ) else (
        call :fIsc1 "!pafIfZs!\%%q"
    )
)
goto :eof
:fIsc1
    echo 1 %1
goto :eof
:fIn


:scIn
rem endlocal
pause
rem exit /b
```

should interact with every file/folder in it's parent folder and every sub folder, and list paths to the every item, 2wice for files, but running it with a:

```
E:\t t\
__ t.cmd
__ t1\
__ __ t1.txt
__ __ t2\
__ __ __ t2.txt
__ t3\
__ __ t3.txt
```

tree, gives this output:

```
"E:\t t\t.cmd\"
1 "E:\t t\t.cmd"
"E:\t t\t1\"
"E:\t t\t1\t2\"
"E:\t t\t1\t2\t3\"
1 "E:\t t\t1\t2\t3"
```

why?

Comment: you `call :fIsc` with one parameter, but the subroutine wants two parameters

Comment: You `Call :fIsc` but immediately after that the code will enter the same subroutine, because you've not prevented it. You should follow that line with an `Exit` or `GoTo` command.

Comment: @ Stephan where do you see the 2nd?
__________
@Compo i do not completely understand "immediately .. will enter the same subroutine", but wouldn't the `exit` ot `goto` break the upper/previous loops (the main point is spamming the `for`-s for each subfolder so after it's one done, the upper ones would keep running) ?

Comment: sorry, it's `:fIsc1`

Comment: llias, a batch file runs line by line, top to bottom and `Call` returns to the next command after having finished that `Call`. So after `call :fIsc "!pafIf:~0,-1!"`, the next line enters the `:fIsc` subroutine again. You may or may not be aware, but after having entered the `:fIsc1` and/or `:fIn` labels you have `GoTo :EOF` and `Exit /B` instructions, but these do not exit the script, they would actually return to the next command after the initial `Call` command. I cannot make it any clearer than that!

Comment: @Compo good point, it was my mistake and i corrected the example, but it doesn't answers the described issues in the result.

Comment: Correct, as this is the comment area, not the answer section. Unfortunately I cannot answer your question because I have absolutely no idea what it is you're trying to achieve. You question is not clear enough for me to help you unless you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55452123/edit) it to explain the task and what what you want to output, instead of just showing us what it does output.

Comment: @Compo it seemed pretty obvious for me, but i added an example

Comment: @llias, thanks for providing the expected output, by I'm afraid to say that your task is still unclear to me. Can you please try to better explain what you're trying to achieve. Perhaps simply telling us what each of the items on each of the expected output lines is supposed to be, would be sufficient, _and/or maybe the output from `Tree "%CD%" /F`_

Comment: @Compo i've enhanced the description, but its not needed to know the final target to find out why the script gives such output, the tree that the script was applied to was/are listed ( " D:\t t [(target)]\1\2\3 " )

Comment: @Ilias: did you ever consider using `forfiles` for such a thing? This feature/command has been written especially for use cases like yours.

Comment: @Compo there is multiple different ways to archive to required result, i hope on figuring out what goes wrong in this/such script, since its a serious educational case.

Comment: @Compo, oh, and thanks for the link/mention, its informative

Comment: @Ilias `dir` returns only names from the provided path (`cd` if not provided). As you try to recurse, you build the full path with `%~fq`. With just the name, how do you consider a full path can be built and be valid. The modifiers can only use the current directory to prepend to the name that `dir` provided. This is why `for /r` returns full paths, else you may not be able to build valid paths (using modifiers) from just names.

Comment: @michael_heath sorry for the delay, notification was coming too long, yes, this makes sense now, thank you, __________
the mistake came from some time ago when, i saw the paths unfold the same way i tryed here, so i thought that the `dir` items even with it's `/b` flag, still carry more data then they show on a pure call (like `!v!`), __________
in conjunction with what you saying, i guess they was getting valid because the active directory was changing

Comment: @michael_heath and may you be wrong on the `%~f` ? (since in a not 'serialized' `for`, it unfolds the `%q` pretty well, regardless of {the script's} active dir.)

Comment: @Ilias You are welcome to try and prove me wrong. `%q` is just a name returned by `dir /b` in a child process and `f` modifier causes a full path to be built, but from what? See my updated answer for example and details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion
cd /D "%~dp0"


set pafIf=%~dp0
call :fIsc "!pafIf:~0,-1!"
goto fIn
:fIsc
setlocal
set "pafIfZs=%1"
set pafIfZs=!pafIfZs:"=!
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%q in ('dir "!pafIfZs!" /b') do (
    echo "!pafIfZs!\%%q\"
    if exist "!pafIfZs!\%%q\" (
        call :fIsc "!pafIfZs!\%%q"
    ) else (
        call :fIsc1 "!pafIfZs!\%%q"
    )
)
goto :eof
:fIsc1
    echo 1 %1
goto :eof
:fIn


:scIn
rem endlocal
pause
rem exit /b
```

For educational purposes, as `for /r` or `dir /s /b` can do recursion.

This code will pass the full path as it recurses.

Added `setlocal` to keep variables local for each recursive `call`.
Without `setlocal`, `!pafIfZs!` be changed and once the recursive
`call` returns, the `for` loop continues with a modified `!pafIfZs!`
that is invalid for the current `call`.

Output with `setlocal`:

> ```
> "E:\t t\t.cmd\"
> 1 "E:\t t\t.cmd"
> "E:\t t\t1\"
> "E:\t t\t1\t1.txt\"
> 1 "E:\t t\t1\t1.txt"
> "E:\t t\t1\t2\"
> "E:\t t\t1\t2\t2.txt\"
> 1 "E:\t t\t1\t2\t2.txt"
> "E:\t t\t3\"
> "E:\t t\t3\t3.txt\"
> 1 "E:\t t\t3\t3.txt"
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

Output without `setlocal`:

> ```
> "E:\t t\t.cmd\"
> 1 "E:\t t\t.cmd"
> "E:\t t\t1\"
> "E:\t t\t1\t1.txt\"
> 1 "E:\t t\t1\t1.txt"
> "E:\t t\t1\t2\"
> "E:\t t\t1\t2\t2.txt\"
> 1 "E:\t t\t1\t2\t2.txt"
> "E:\t t\t1\t2\t3\"
> 1 "E:\t t\t1\t2\t3"
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

Current `tree`:

> ```
> E:\T T
> |   t.cmd
> |
> +---t1
> |   |   t1.txt
> |   |
> |   \---t2
> |           t2.txt
> |
> \---t3
>         t3.txt
> ```

---

The modifier for `f` in `%%~fq` may generate invalid paths while
recursing, as the current directory is not changing and only a
name (*including extension*) is provided with `dir /b`.
With just a name, expect the modifier to prepend the
current directory to the name.

Example of modifer being invalid if current directory is different:

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d "D:\t t"

for /f "delims=" %%q in ('dir /b') do (
    cd /d "E:\"
    echo %%~fq
    if exist "%%~fq" (echo Valid) else echo Invalid
    echo(
)
```

Output:

> ```
> D:\t t\t.cmd
> Valid
>
> E:\t1
> Invalid
>
> E:\t2
> Invalid
>
> E:\t3
> Invalid
> ```

This demonstrates that the full path of `%%~fq` is built
from the current directory as `%%q` is not a valid full
path to start with and is just either a filename or a
folder name. This is why `for /r` and `dir /b /s` provide
full paths instead of just filename or folder name.

Comment: i've accepted it too fast, in a test the script was not detecting a `D:\t t\1\2\file.txt`, also after changing `%..%` to `!..!` it got broken in other way and listed paths where every next checked folder was a sub of previous.

Comment: Updated answer. `%..%` variables was my bad choice for `call` recursion as change to `!..!` show difference, thanks for the reply. With `setlocal` absent in the called label, the value of `!pafIfZs!` can be incorrect for the current call.

Comment: `%%~f[_]` get the data by some unknown ways, and it can make mistakes, `dir /b` provides only the names, without any other data (this should be correct i guess),
The code output is: ` "E:\t t\t.cmd\"
1 "E:\t t\t.cmd"
"E:\t t\t1\"
"E:\t t\t1\t2\"
"E:\t t\t3\"
Press any key to continue . . . ` , may you have made some mistake during pasting it here?

Comment: You are using it on a wrong tree, reread the main post (1st), the code doesn't go under 2nd level

Comment: Sorry, corrected the tree and executed `tree` and posted to confirm structure.

Comment: The output on my side are same (the wrong one), i'm running Win 10 1803

Comment: I am on Win 7. Tried in Win 10 1803 Virtual Machine with [desktop image](https://imgur.com/0uqooh7). Your GIF seems OK by what I can see. I just cannot explain the difference between your results and mine.

Comment: just in case, have you tried to run the file directly (not from the cmd.exe)?
Possible to be somehow related to somewhich internal settings, can be not easy to find out, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Same output if I double click on the file on Win 7 and Win 10 VM. Try `type t.cmd` on your file and see if it print good. Perhaps a file encoding problem if you have strange characters appearing. Check line endings. Try testing on a friends computer. Otherwise, out of ideas.

Comment: [png](https://photos.app.goo.gl/TKRMUuX7aahfKWZb7), fun thing that VSC shows "UTF-8" for ANSI files